# Angular 8 with Material using a table. When using mobile browser (Chrome) it half opens rows by itself

Tags: angular, mobile, angular-material

I have an Angular 8 application using Material v8.2.3 and I am using a table with expanding rows.

It work's fine with desktop browsers.  However when I access it using the latest chrome, Edge, or Firefox on my mobile phone the table will automatically partially open some of the rows, and this is without clicking on them.  None of the rows open fully, as it would if I click on a row.  The rows that it opens appears to be random. [Mobile View of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ybx.jpg)

I am using an Android phone.  BTW, the DuckDuck-Go mobile browser app does not exhibit this behavior and it works fine.

My application is live if you want to check it out [here](https://tv.feuersoft.com).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Google ads were causing the issue.  Even though the rows were closed, the Google ads have some styling that makes the row open a small amount.  The fix was to just put an ngIf guard around the div using this: *ngIf="element === expandedElement", that way only one google ad will be in the DOM at any one time, which is much more efficient.